# Elasticsearch Cluster deployed with docker, ansible, and authentication

Tags: docker, authentication, elasticsearch

This is going to be an odd post with how basic it is, but I'm stuck. I have turned this docker-compose file into an ansible job that spins up the cluster:

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  es01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.9.2
    container_name: es01
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es02,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - elastic
  es02:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.9.2
    container_name: es02
    environment:
      - node.name=es02
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data02:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - elastic
  es03:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.9.2
    container_name: es03
    environment:
      - node.name=es03
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es02
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data03:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - elastic

volumes:
  data01:
    driver: local
  data02:
    driver: local
  data03:
    driver: local

networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge
```

The problem is when I add security to the cluster, then the cluster returns a master_not_discovered_exception. All I'm adding extra to es01 is `xpack.security.enabled: true`, `ELASTIC_PASSWORD: "password"`
and `xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true`

Any idea where to go from here?

Comment: can you share the elasticsearch logs?

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
```

requires you first to generate and add certificates to the services in order to encrypt inter-node communication. There are several steps to go:

1. Get some certificates, at least generate SSL certificates by you own
2. Distribute certificates to all nodes via volumes
3. Configure the certificates and passwords via keystore

Please have a look at the general documentation of [encrypting communications](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/encrypting-communications.html) and then the [docker relevant steps](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/configuring-tls-docker.html) you need to go.

Just for the case you don't want to encrypt the inter-node communication but the http-endpoint (rest-api), that´s what

```
xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: true
```

is made for. The procedure to get this working is very similar to the previous one and covered by the mentioned docs.